# Self Managed MySQL Database for WSO2 Identity Server 5.9.0 CPU issue and how to use hazelcast in WSO2 IS cluster?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

We have a WSO2 cluster setup with 2 EC2 nodes having a MySQL database connected to both of them.

WSO2 Node Cloud EC2 Instance Type - t2.small

MySQL Cloud EC2 Instance Type - t2.small

WSO2 Version - 5.9.0

Architecture-

2 x WSO2 Node

1 x MySQL Database

1 x Application Load Balancer

[image]

We are experiencing unusually high CPU(~99%) at the common database server which is sitting behind both the WSO2 node even in an idol state.

MySQL Query Logs-

I also implemented slow query logs for logging query above 5 seconds but it was empty too.
[image]

I also tried updating the instance to t3.medium it is having 2 cores and 4 GiB RAM.
But there is no effect on the performance the WSO2 IS APIs are still taking too much time.

Will Using hazelcast for caching help this purpose?

Also, do I need a separate server for hazelcast and if so can you please tell me which version of hazelcast is best compatible with WSO2 IS 5.9.0?

Am I doing something wrong in the setup?

```
[server]
hostname = "localhost"
node_ip = "127.0.0.1"
base_path = "https://$ref{server.hostname}:${carbon.management.port}"

[super_admin]
username = "username@wso2.com"
password = "password"
create_admin_account = true

[tenant_mgt]
enable_email_domain= true

[user_store]
type = "database"
scim_enabled = true
user_name_attribute = "mail"
username_java_script_regex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'
username_java_regex='^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}'

[database.identity_db]
type = "mysql"
url= "jdbc:mysql://<SOME_IP>:3306/regdb?useSSL=false"
username = "<SOME_USER>"
password = "<SOME_PASSWORD>"
driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
url= "jdbc:mysql://<SOME_IP>:3306/regdb?useSSL=false"
username = "<SOME_USER>"
password = "<SOME_PASSWORD>"
driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

[[cache.manager]]
name = "LocalClaimInvalidationCache"
timeout = "300"
capacity = "5000"

[carbon_health_check]
enable= true

[keystore.primary]
name = "wso2carbon.jks"
password = "wso2carbon"

[admin_service.wsdl]
enable = true

authentication.authenticator.session_handler.parameters.max_session_count = "100"
```

Comment: This URL does not indicate t2. are meant to be used for production instances. https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t2/

Comment: Even so, if you could provide - Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions that may enable you to stay on your t2's.